# How can I match deep link URL patterns in the Android well-known assetlinks.json file?

Tags: android, deep-linking, url-pattern

I have an Android app which needs to handle deep links, and I have installed a `<server>/.well-known/assetlinks.json` file [as documented](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/getting-started#quick-usage-example).

I am hoping I can use the `assetlinks.json` file to specify a more complex URL matching pattern than the AndroidManifest.xml `intent-filter` allows.

Currently my `assetlinks.json` looks like this:

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.example.myapp",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["12:34:...:CD:EF"]
  }
}]
```

What are the options for the `"relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"]` entry? The name surely implies that there must be other options than handling all URLs, but I can't see how to specify what URLs to handle.

The [Statement List Syntax](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/statements) doesn't offer any example other than `common.handle_all_urls` and the [detail](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/relation-strings) just says "If you want to create a statement that does not fit one of these statement types, you can define your own unique string." But how?

For example I want to:

- Handle all URLs matching `https://server.example.com/project/*`
- Except DO NOT handle `https://server.example.com/project/upload`

The app's AndroidManifest `intent-filter` has URL configuration options through `android:pathPrefix` etc, but AFAIK it does not allow this kind of exclusion which is why I am hoping to use the `assetlinks.json` file. (The intent-filter `android:pathAdvancePattern` property does not work below Android 12, so is not enough to solve the problem.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling specific routes in Android M app links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840262/handling-specific-routes-in-android-m-app-links)

Answer (score 1):

I'd still like to know a full answer to this question explaining how the `assetlinks.json` file `delegate_permission` entry works, but I have a workaround for my problem. My statement "The intent-filter `android:pathAdvancePattern` property does not work below Android 12" turned out to be incorrect and it *does* work, at least back to Android 7/SDK 24 when I tested. To achieve the exclusion I wanted, I used this intent filter on my Activity:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:host="server.example.com" />
    <data android:pathAdvancedPattern="/project/[^(upload)]+" />
</intent-filter>
```

I am building with:

```
minSdkVersion=24
compileSdkVersion=33
targetSdkVersion=33
```